# Need help bootstraping phalcon on Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache, phalcon

I am working on **Ubuntu 15.04** recently I installed phalcon as per the [guidelines](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/install.html)

It installed successfully and I could see phalcon listed in **phpinfo()**.
I was following along the [tutorial](https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial.html) on the official website.

My **.htaccess** files are also working fine

```
#/tutorial/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule ((?s).*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

#/tutorial/public/.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

However when I create **index.php** => bootstrap file in the public directory and load the page on server. Phalcon says : **PhalconException: IndexController handler class cannot be loaded**

This is my **public/index.php** file

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Loader;
use Phalcon\Mvc\View;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Application;
use Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Url as UrlProvider;
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as DbAdapter;

try {

// Register an autoloader
$loader = new Loader();
$loader->registerDirs(array(
    '../app/controllers/',
    '../app/models/'
))->register();

// Create a DI
$di = new FactoryDefault();

// Setup the view component
$di->set('view', function () {
    $view = new View();
    $view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');
    return $view;
});

// Setup a base URI so that all generated URIs include the "tutorial" folder
$di->set('url', function () {
    $url = new UrlProvider();
    $url->setBaseUri('/');
    return $url;
});

// Handle the request
$application = new Application($di);

echo $application->handle()->getContent();

} catch (\Exception $e) {
     echo "PhalconException: ", $e->getMessage();
}
```

I searched alot but can't anything that works for me. 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

follow this tutorial:
https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/tutorial.html

Section "Creating Controller"
Basically tou need to create the IndexController under the folder /apps/controllers/ and it should looks like this

```
<?php
use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class IndexController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        echo "<h1>Hello!</h1>";
    }
}
```